# Google translate in angular 5 not working

Tags: angular5, google-translate

I want to add multi language support in my website.However most of the data is coming from API so I cant make a JSON of it.
I am using [Google Translate](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_google_translate.asp) but it is not working.
Can you please share steps as how to inject it in my angular 5 application?
Much thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Then you should consider using [Cloud Translation API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/) instead of Google Translate for your purposes. To get started with the Cloud Translation API in your language of choice, please look into this [Cloud Translation API Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-nodejs) for more details.